# This is my class for httppost request ,so i want to send the response code with error message when the request is come into the system

Tags: httprequest, httppost, third-party

This is my code, what I want to send is if request is sucessfully created then send code 201 with sucess message and if not created then send 501 with error message

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/lookeropportunity')
global class OpportunityController {
    @HttpPost
    global static  void createOpp(){
        try{
            RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
            RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
            //Access the request body with input data coming in the JSON format 
            String jSONRequestBody=request.requestBody.toString().trim(); 
            List<VendorPayoutJSON> vendorPayoutOppList =new List<VendorPayoutJSON>();
            OpportunityServiceInterfaceImpl opportunityserviceinterfaceimpl = new OpportunityServiceInterfaceImpl();
            OppList = opportunityserviceinterfaceimpl.convertJSONDataToOppList(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString());
            system.debug('OppList '+OppList);
            if(!OppList.isEmpty()){
                opportunityserviceinterfaceimpl.createOpportunityForExistingAccount(OppList);
            }
        }
        Catch(exception ex ){
            APIException    customer= new APIException(ex.getLineNumber(),ex.getCause(),ex.getMessage(),'Error occured');
             throw customer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the Apex Reference Guide for the RestResponse class which is available through the [RestContext class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_restcontext.htm)

```
RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
if (yourSuccessCondition) {
    res.statusCode = 201;
}
else {
    res.statusCode = 500;  // 501 not supported, see doc
}
```